# Italic in Storyboard in Attributed text doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, nsattributedstring

In right options panel in XCode I defined the attributed text with Italic like it is below:

[image]

But when i compile the code, there is no italic now, like it is below:

[image]

My font is well attached to the project and marked in info.plist as it is below:
[image]

How to fix this problem?

Comment: try to set it in plain, test it, and then change it to attributed. 
I had similar issues with bold, font-size etc. For some weird reason it didn't work as it should.